# Two moving and rotating bodies, how to approximate hitbox of a trajectory of a point on one body in the coordinate system of other

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, physics, geometry

The game is in 2D.

Let's say I have two bodies: A and B, each with position, angle, velocity vector, and angular velocity (I'm not sure yet if I should be using angles, or rotation matrices).

Given a point on A, I want to get the AABB for its trajectory (during the current tick) in the coordinate system of B. The AABB can be approximate (larger than necessary) to simplify the calculation.

By trajectory during the current tick, I mean for `0 <= t <= 1`, all positions `pos + vel * t` and angles `angle + angular_vel * t`.

---

What this is for:

I'm trying to simulate physics between multiple tile grids. My current plan is to store a BVH tree of edges for each grid (this part is done), then test collisions by looping every edge of one object, querying all near edges using the BVH tree of the other object.

On collision, I'm planning to binary-search the precise collision location/time. To do it fast, for each edge of A, I want to build a list of edges of B that can possibly overlap with it during the current tick. And to build the list, I need an AABB to query the BVH of B with.

---

So far my best idea so far is to extend the AABB in the direction of A's velocity by that amount, then extend in all directions by

```
length(point_in_a_coords) * abs(a.angular_vel)
+
(
    length(point_in_a_coords)
    + max(length(a.pos - b.pos), length((a.pos + a.vel) - (b.pos + b.vel)))
) * abs(b.angular_vel)
```

With some approximated `length(point_in_a_coords)` that is greater or equal to the actual value, or with this value baked into the edge when creating it.

But this is probably far from optimal.